# C# Unity 3D NAudio throws NullReferenceException while checking for default audio endpoint

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, .net-3.5, naudio

I've just installed Unity 3D because I wanted to make a simple game. There is one problem with the NAudio library though.

This is my code:

```
var enumerator = new MMDeviceEnumerator();

if (enumerator.HasDefaultAudioEndpoint(DataFlow.Render, Role.Multimedia)) //<--- crashes here
{
   //...
}
```

This is literally all Unity says when trying to launch the game:

> **NullReferenceException:** Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object NAudio.CoreAudioApi.MMDeviceEnumerator.HasDefaultAudioEndpoint
>   (DataFlow dataFlow, Role role)

I don't understand why it throws this kind of error here.
Could it be that the library might not be compatible with this version of net framework (version 3.5)?

**EDIT:** the variable enumerator can't be null, so stop flagging this post as a duplicate of 'What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?'

I've also tried using this libary: https://code.google.com/archive/p/naudio-with-unity3d/downloads
That library only doesn't contain the `HasDefaultAudioEndpoint()` function, so I just tried getting the audio endpoint directly by calling `GetDefaultAudioEndpoint()` but it still threw that same error on that line.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Technically, that is not the line of code that's crashing. That's the *call* to the function that contains the line of code that is crashing.

Comment: You should Debug your `enumerator` variable. It's possible that a variable that you are trying to use is null and that's why you are getting a NullReferenceException. Since this is the only text you provided us. I'm going to guess it's your `var enumerator`.

Comment: I'll say this again: `NullPointerException` => JAVA, `NullReferenceException` => .NET. Not sure why your title says Pointer.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto sorry, mixed that up while writing the title

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not your code. If you look at the source code for [`HasDefaultAudioEndpoint`](https://github.com/naudio/NAudio/blob/e3b8353e2f60e1ce3f55251c2c9e93c5ff44ea70/NAudio/CoreAudioApi/MMDeviceEnumerator.cs#L83), it looks like this:

```
public bool HasDefaultAudioEndpoint(DataFlow dataFlow, Role role)
{
    IMMDevice device = null;
    int hresult = ((IMMDeviceEnumerator)realEnumerator).GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(dataFlow, role, out device);
    ...
}
```

Where `realEnumerator` is:

```
[ComImport, Guid("BCDE0395-E52F-467C-8E3D-C4579291692E")]
class MMDeviceEnumeratorComObject
{
}
```

It's not checking whether `realEnumerator != null`, most likely because Unity was not considered and it doesn't support some COM+ interop.

If you look at [this question](https://answers.unity.com/questions/218120/c-unity3d-and-naudio-enumerateaudioendpoints-throw.html) from 2012, 4 years later the OP answered it never worked, and had to create a c++ DLL for this.

Comment: Welp, screw this.

Comment: @TomLenc So... did my answer help you or...?

Comment: I found a library called CSCore which had all the functions from NAudio and it finally works. Now I only need to process the data somehow.