# Get system audio stream buffer for visualization

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I tried getting the system output device stream buffer using NAudio but I had this problem:

[C# Unity 3D NAudio throws NullPointerException while checking for default audio endpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48217715/c-sharp-unity-3d-naudio-throws-nullpointerexception-while-checking-for-default-a)

The same exact code mentioned in that question works just fine in my windows forms projects(outside Unity).

NAudio would be the perfect solution for me, but it just doesn't want to cooperate with Unity for some reason. So is there any free alternative to NAudio or any other free possible solution for this problem?

Comment: Please read [ask]. Questions asking to recommend libraries are off-topic.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto the **or** is there for a reason.

Comment: "any other free possible solution" is still the same. The reason the *or* is there does not make this question on-topic.

Comment: @rene it's in the post I mentioned.

Comment: see if this helps, probably solves both issues https://code.google.com/archive/p/naudio-with-unity3d/

Comment: @rene Oh.. I might've forgotten to mention that I've already tried that library and it doesn't work either.. Same error.

The version of that library only doesn't have the ``HasDefaultAudioEndpoint()`` function in it, so I directly used ``GetDefaultAudioEndpoint()``

Comment: You might want to include all your research in your question.

Answer (score 0):

I personally have used [FMOD](https://www.fmod.com/) to great success, for help on how to integrate into unity you can look at an open source project that utilises it to great effect :) here: https://github.com/OrderOfThePorcupine/ProjectPorcupine.

Comment: Can FMOD get the audio buffer of an output device, such as speakers?

Comment: I believe so :)